# Changing specific link daily by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change a link on the page on daily basis starting from a startdate X (let's say from 20th Nov = day 1) via JavaScript or jQuery. It has to be a specific link every day.

My solution so far:
So I added the links within `div#daily-gal`, added a value to each link and hide them via css-class `.hide (display:none;)`. So far so good. Now comes the tricky part for me: I want to set a startday by date and see how many days have passed (today - startday) and give that as a value to a  variable (linkval). The function should now be: If the set value of the link matches with my linkval the class .show (display:block;) should be manipulated within the link.

I'm hanging in taxonimic problems here (or even understanding issues ;) as I'm quite new to jQuery/JS. If anybody would have an idea where I'm wrong I'd be happy.

The js-filde: http://jsfiddle.net/Mdq49/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="daily-gal">
    <a href="http://www.eamplelink.com/A" class="hide" value="1">link1</a>
    <a href="http://www.eamplelink.com/B" class="hide" value="2">link2</a>
    <a href="http://www.eamplelink.com/C" class="hide" value="3">link3</a>
    <a href="http://www.eamplelink.com/D" class="hide" value="4">link4</a>
    <a href="http://www.eamplelink.com/E" class="hide" value="5">link5</a>
    <a href="http://www.eamplelink.com/F" class="hide" value="6">link6</a>
</div>
<!-- End daily gal -->
```

**jQuery:**

```
var startdate = new Date("November 20, 2013 00:00:00 GET")
var today = new Date();
count = Math.floor((startdate.getTime() - today.getTime()) / 1000);
var linkval = cont * -1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    if linkval === a.value {
        $('#daily-gal a').attr('http://www.eamplelink.com/', ['linkval']).addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Typo cont should be count `var linkval = count*-1`;

Comment: A global variable that counts today-startday.

Comment: You have a typo @ChrisKlein..check previous comment

Comment: Hi Ani, thank's a lot! I'll correct that.

Comment: Also, what is a.value ?..

Comment: Jes that is the taxonomic problems as I don't know how to express it correctly.

Comment: I want to check if linkval is identical with the value I've set for the link.

Comment: first of all a.value will not have anything. I am not sure what value you are expecting in a.value ? Meaning, how does one get toknow on which date what value a.value suppose to have ?

Comment: hm, I wrote within the link value="1", value="2" in hope to get a dynamic identifier for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>You have a typo in your code: `GET` Should be Greenw. Merid. Time so **`GMT`**</sup>
Using the `%` modulo (reminder) operator it's quite an easy task

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aPomeBIb/2/edit)**

```
var links = [
  "http://www.eamplelink.com/A",
  "http://www.eamplelink.com/B",
  "http://www.eamplelink.com/C",
  "http://www.eamplelink.com/D",
  "http://www.eamplelink.com/E"
];
// Set a date in the future:
var start = new Date("November 14, 2013 00:00:00 GMT"),    
    today = new Date(),
    days  = Math.ceil((start.getTime()-today.getTime())/1000/60/60/24); 


$('#daily-gal a').attr('href', links[days%links.length] );
```

If today is 14 Nov. let's say we need the `A` link, now set to *November 20*,
that's **6** days from now, and you should get the B link:

`0A, 1B, 2C, 3D, 4E,` `%` `(5)0A, (6)1B`

> **Important note!** The above will work if the set date is a date in the future.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="daily-gal">
  <a href="#">TEST</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @ChrisKlein I'd also add an minuted interval to re-check the date, I might tab your page, leave my PC on and come back tomorrow clicking the undesired link ;) Or I might visit your page at 11:59 and than after a minute ... :)